# R ggplot geom_line() doesn't give the wanted result

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm new to R and having some problems with ggplot2.
I have tried plotting a geom_line over a ggplot with this code :

```
gplot(shm_data ,aes(X, Y, fill= Count)) + 
  geom_tile(aes(X,Y,alpha=Count))+
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours=c("yellow","orange","red"),na.value = NA,guide=FALSE)+
  scale_y_continuous(trans = "reverse")+
  scale_alpha(guide=FALSE,range = c(0.25,1))+
  ggtitle(paste0("heat map of ",
                 substring(session_name,1, regexpr("-", session_name) - 1)))+
  geom_line(data=smooth_cm,aes(x,y),inherit.aes=FALSE,na.rm=TRUE)
```

the code results in this plot over my ggplot :

[image]

and I want it to be as a regular plot over my ggplot ,
that looks like this :

[image]

The code for the plot above is :

```
plot(y~x , ylim = rev(range(y,na.rm=TRUE)),type='l')
```

I can't understand the problem and thankyou in advance for taking the time to answer my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess (lacking data) is that the (bad) scribbles is the order it is found in the frame, regardless of the order of the `x`-axis variable. Use `geom_path` instead:

```r
gplot(shm_data ,aes(X, Y, fill= Count)) + 
  geom_tile(aes(X,Y,alpha=Count))+
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours=c("yellow","orange","red"),na.value = NA,guide=FALSE)+
  scale_y_continuous(trans = "reverse")+
  scale_alpha(guide=FALSE,range = c(0.25,1))+
  ggtitle(paste0("heat map of ",
                 substring(session_name,1, regexpr("-", session_name) - 1)))+
  geom_path(data=smooth_cm,aes(x,y),inherit.aes=FALSE,na.rm=TRUE)
```

From [`?geom_path`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_path.html):

> `geom_path()` connects the observations in the order in which they appear in the data. `geom_line()` connects them in order of the variable on the x axis.